# TrueAnomaly of planet orbit as a function?

Tags: physics, curated-data, astronomy

It is possible to obtain the true anomaly of a planet this way:

```
In[1]:= PlanetData["Earth", "TrueAnomaly"]
Out[1]= Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{7, 18.8561}], MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes"}]]
```

However, the true anomaly is actually a function of time. So I suppose it gives the anomaly for the current moment. Is it possible to obtain this with a `DateObject` (or similar) parameter? I already have an implementation of the Kepler equations, but I am curious if there is a simpler (and perhaps more precise) way to obtain the anomalies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found this solution:

```
PlanetData["Earth",
           EntityProperty["Planet",
                          "TrueAnomaly",
                          {"Date" -> DateObject[{2020, 1, 1}]}]]
```